# JavaScript: Print user time zone 'initials' to screen

Tags: javascript, datetime, user-interface, datetime-format

I've beaten my head against the desk on this, because I can't accept that it's not a thing. Is it possible to print a the users timezone to the page with JavaScript?

Like (EST) or (MST) ? Here's my code so far.

```
var today = new Date();
                    //var UTCstring = today.toUTCString();
                    var date = today.toDateString();
                    var time = today.toLocaleTimeString();
                    document.getElementById("localTimeID").innerHTML = "Your time: <strong>" + date + " " + time + "</strong>";
```

[image: What I've got]

In the Picture I want the bottom time stamp to match the top and I'm so close! The top time stamp is being made by ColdFusion.

Comment: There's no cross-browser reliable way to do this, but there are libraries like Moment.JS and Datejs that handle it.

Comment: Untagging ColdFusion as it's got nothing to do with ColdFusion

Comment: I've used Moment.Js before. And it looks like I may have to again. I just prefer not adding libraries when I only plan one feature from it.